# "Unable to find project context to attach debugger for xxx" on Android Studio Iguana

Tags: android-studio-lguana

After update my android studio to the version of "Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1 Build #AI-232.10300.40.2321.11567975, built on March 13, 2024", **can not use the debugger.**

**Error tips below:**

Error running 'Attach debug to process'

Unable to find project context to attach debugger for process system_process

Anyone can help me, thx

no use when restart android studio or reboot my computer